# How to let a property change bubble up?

Tags: wpf

I have the following structure:
Window1 -> UserControlA -> UserControlB -> UserControlC

Each has its own view model. How can I create a property on UserControlA that depends on a property of UserControlC?

The only thing I can think of is to expose C's property changed event from B so I can listen for the C's events from A and update A's dependency property. The problem is that this seems WAY too contrived so I think there has to be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the `Dependency Properties` to achieve this. You need to expose dp in all your user controls. Bind the property of `UserControlC` with `UserControlB` and then `UserControlA`. This way whenever property in `UserControlC` is changed, property in `UserControlA` is also changed.

A.xaml.cs

```
class VewModelA : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    prop TextA {get {return thevalue;} set : set thevalue & RaisePropertyChanged("TextA")}
}
```

B.xaml.cs

```
class ViewModelB : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    prop TextB {get {return thevalue;} set : set thevalue & RaisePropertyChanged("TextB")}
}
```

C.xaml.cs

```
class ViewModelC : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    prop TextC {get {return thevalue;} set : set thevalue & RaisePropertyChanged("TextC")}
}
```

A.xaml

```
<controls:B TextB={Binding TextA, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

B.xaml

```
<controls:C TextC={Binding TextB, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Whenever Text of C is changed, binding updates the value of TextA. And definitely you have to map the dp with their corresponding viewmodel properties in their control template.

Comment: Sorry for I thought I understood this. When I create a DP on the control C the "TextC" property gets/sets the "TextCProperty". How can I map it to the viewmodel property?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do:

1. Do as you mentioned in the question: let each parent observe its child.
2. Use RoutedEvents: expose [a RoutedEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) on C and handled it on A.

**EDIT**

After thinking more about your question:

If it's a property of the ViewModel of C you want to bubble up you can only use the first option because RoutedEvents are only supported on UI controls.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be to use the EventAggregator mechanisms that are available as part of Prism http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/